# How do I read and print a binary file in C?

Tags: c, fwrite, fread, bin

I'm struggling reading and printing from a binary file. Below you can see the code with main function. I was able to implement the write function, but struggling with the read part where I want to read from and print the binary file that was created.

Happy for every answer and help!

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct Person
{
  char name[40];
  int  age;
};

void read()
{
    puts("help");
}

void write()
{
  struct Person ps[] = { {"Tom", 25}, {"Adam", 35} };

  FILE *fo = fopen("1.bin", "wb");

  fwrite(ps, sizeof(struct Person), 2, fo);
  fwrite(ps, sizeof(ps), 1, fo);

  fclose(fo);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  switch(argv[1][0])
  {
    case 'w':
      puts("w");
      write();
      break;
    case 'r':
      puts("r");
      read();
      break;
    default:
      puts("Error in command line");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag C++ for C questions, they are **not** the same language.

Comment: `void read() { struct Person ps[4]; FILE* fi = fopen("1.bin", "rb"); fread(ps, sizeof(struct Person), 4, fi); fclose(fi); }`

Comment: In `write()`, you need one or the other of those `fwrite` calls, not both of them...

Answer (score 2):

I renamed your functions with a "person_" prefix as not to conflict with standard functions (if you ever want to use those in your program).  Implemented `person_read()` but passing a pointer and count `n`.  Alternatively, `person_write()` could write an initial record count.  You could also implement a function that counts number of records in your file, or insist on `person_read()` allocating a suitable array on the heap and return a pointer.  You could also read a record at a time till EOF but that is more a design change.  Fixed the segfault if you were not specifying any arguments.  Check for errors of `fopen()`, `fread()` and `fwrite()`.  Consider using an unsigned (char) for age instead of an `int`.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAME_LEN 40
#define PATH "1.bin"

struct Person {
    char name[NAME_LEN];
    int age;
};

void person_print(struct Person *ps, unsigned n) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("name: %s, age; %d\n", (ps+i)->name, (ps+i)->age);
    }
}

void person_read(struct Person *ps, unsigned n) {
    FILE *fo = fopen(PATH, "rb");
    if(!fo) {
        printf("fopen failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
    if(fread(ps, sizeof(struct Person), n, fo) != n) {
        printf("fread failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    fclose(fo);
}

void person_write(struct Person *ps, unsigned n) {
    FILE *fo = fopen(PATH, "wb");
    if(!fo) {
        printf("fopen failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return;
    }
    if(fwrite(ps, sizeof(struct Person), n, fo) != n) {
        printf("fwrite failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    fclose(fo);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    switch(argc > 1 ? argv[1][0] : '\0') {
        case 'r': {
            struct Person ps[2];
            person_read(ps, sizeof(ps) / sizeof(*ps));
            person_print(ps, sizeof(ps) / sizeof(*ps));
            break;
        }
        case 'w': {
            struct Person ps[] = { {"Tom", 25}, {"Adam", 35} };
            person_write(ps, sizeof(ps) / sizeof(*ps));
            break;
        }
        default:
            puts("Error in command line");
    }
    return 0;
}
```